# How to send messages to people that applied to a Facebook group from a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-groups

As an admin of a Facebook group I can, in the list of new applications where you accept or deny new members, also send messages to people who have applied to become members of the group. Currently these messages are sent from my private account.

I want the sender to be the page that is connected to the page and not exposing my private account. How do I do this?